# Apostrophes returned by sql query not being printed in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, encoding, apostrophe

I'm working with Oracle SQL Developer and the queries I execute are well printed in its console, but not in the Java console either in jsp.

- In debug mode (inspect mode or varibles schede) doesn't even appears the character, it's shown the 2 words together.
- In the Java console appears as '?'
- In the JSP as '[0092]'. Could it be encoding issue?

The query is a simple select:

```
SELECT something, somethingElse FROM myTable where filter = 'someArgument';
```

This is how I retrieve the value after executeQuery():

```
  //here is already not being printed. But the jsp shows it as unreadable character.
  resultSet.getObject(i).toString();
```

This is how I put it in the jsp:

```
stringBuffer.append("<option value='" 
+ mapEntryElement.getKey() + "'>"+ mapEntryElement.getValue().toString() + "</option>");
```

I've tried adding this to the JSP but nothing:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using `getObject(i).toString()` instead of `getString(i)` ? But yes, sounds like it could be a mismatch between the Java locale and database/session settings. Presumably it's a curly quote of some kind (given then `[0092]`, [this one?](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm)), not a normal `'`. You can use the `dump()` function in Oracle to examine the value and see what it really is.

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm using getObject(i).toString() beacuse the method cointainer it's not done by me and I cannot modify it. So I checked out the database table, and you were right, there is an accent or something instead of ( ' ). I did an update with the right String and is working now. Answer the question so I can mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bad written in the database. It was an accent instead of apostrophe